# redis switch values atomically

Tags: list, redis, transactions, atomic, sortedset

I have to have something (could be a list, sorted set, maybe a simple string) 
containing various numbers (non-repeating) and I need to be able to switch some

For example with lists :

```
LRANGE todo:20 0 -1 => "2" "5" "6" "7"
```

Doing my switch : i.e.

```
MULTI

LRANGE todo:20 0 1 => "2" "5" (store them)
LSET todo:20 0 "5"
LSET todo:20 1 "2"

EXEC
```

Final result :

```
LRANGE todo:20 0 -1 => "5" "2" "6" "7"
```

Is there any way that I could do this in a simpler (or better) fashion or is that a "limitation" of REDIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SORT` command.

Store those indexes in a `SET` and store a corresponding score/weight for each index, and sort by it. The score key can be a hash, and you can have many different sets of scores.

Here's an example:
A todo list with 3 parameters, the insertion time, the time it will take to execute, and a priority.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SADD todos 1 2 3
127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET todos:1 insertionTime 1 executionTime 10 priority 5
127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET todos:2 insertionTime 2 executionTime 25 priority 1
127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET todos:3 insertionTime 5 executionTime 4 priority 7
```

To get the list sorted by each one:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SORT todos by todos:*->insertionTime
1) "1"
2) "2"
3) "3"
127.0.0.1:6379> SORT todos by todos:*->executionTime
1) "3"
2) "1"
3) "2"
127.0.0.1:6379> SORT todos by todos:*->priority
1) "2"
2) "1"
3) "3"
```

If you also save the task itself (or any other data) in this hash or any other key in the same Redis db, you can get it in the same single call with the optional `GET` argument:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET todos:1 task "do something"
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET todos:2 task "do something else"
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET todos:3 task "do this other thing"

127.0.0.1:6379> SORT todos by todos:*->priority get todos:*->task
1) "do something else"
2) "do something"
3) "do this other thing"
```

Note that the SORT command will not work with Redis cluster as you are accessing multiple keys. And this command time complexity can be very high, you should use it with cautious especially when the usage and the set sizes scale up.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Lua script that does it, then call that in place of your transaction. You could also use modules but that may be overkill if the request is simple.